# How to fit image in mobile view of website

Tags: html, css

I want to fit the image on my website into a div. but I only want to do this when it drops below a certain screen size. For example, in mobile view it will fit inside the div but not in normal web view.
What properties do I need to give in css?

```
<div class="page-title-wrap bg-overlay bg-overlay-dark-3">
    <div class="bg-section"><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>"alt="Background" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From your code it's impossible to say! Maybe you can include your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "show properly" but I'll assume you want it to fill up all available space. With CSS you can do the following using flexbox:

```css
.bg-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}
.bg-section img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}
```

Alterativly if you set the BG image with CSS like this:

```html
<div class="page-title-wrap bg-overlay bg-overlay-dark-3">
    <div class="bg-section" style="background-image: <?php echo $image_path; ?>"></div>
</div>
```

You could then just set the size like this:

```css
.bg-section {
  width:100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```